# Network-wide domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network, wide-area-network

Is there a way to, on my wireless network, have a domain assigned to a network page? For example, could I have "media.com" link to "192.168.0.101/sharedmedia.html"? It would also be good if I could "register" a network-wide TLD, such as "media.shared" (as with .onion URLs on TOR). I'm running apache 2 on a linux machine.

Comment: Do you want a full public domain (needed if you want someone outside your network to reach it by name ... but that needs a public IP address which 192.168.0.101 is NOT), or just a domain-like private name? If the latter, do you want one that won't get mixed up with any real public domain?

Comment: Yes, if you create your own DNS server and point at it, you can tell it to resolve any name to any address.  But this is really not on topic here, nor is it a particularly good question, IMO.  You need to do some basic research on the underlying concepts first.

Comment: @Skaperen It would only be for my network, private IP (192...). If I can do the custom TLD, a mixup wouldn't be relevant, but if that can't be done feasibly, I would want it to override external domains, so that even if I chose something like google.com, I'd see my network page. I'd also rather not edit the hosts file on every device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. You need an internal DNS server. If your clients on your network use your internal DNS server (by say, assigning your internal DNS server to clients via their DHCP leases) you can create your own mini-world-wide-web. Create your own TLDs, overwrite other peoples TLDs, go crazy, create records for whatever you want.

You could watch the world burn by redirecting google.com to yahoo.com and google+ to facebook. The world would be your oyster, but only while in your office. As soon as you leave the office, everything would go back to being normal.